# siunitx: mu is jerky + memory object warning

Tags: siunitx

First of all, I am sorry if this was already mentioned before (I did look at threads with problems regarding mu in siunitx).

The problem is that when I use code:

```
\SI{1}{\micro\metre}
```

I get a warning (in TeXstudio):

```
** WARNING ** -2 memory objects still allocated You may want to report this to tex-k@tug.org
```

and the letter mu itself in the compiled pdf looks "jerky":
[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\micro\metre}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? Are you perhaps compiling with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Hi @egreg and hi everyone else. I managed to resolve the issue by installing newer version of MikTeX. I was using ProText 3.1.3 installation package previously, and installed siunitx package by using package manager of MikTeX (MikTeX given by ProTeX 3.1.3).

Comment: Solved by updating the TeX distribution.